# Set my mobile phone to silent mode

Tags: android, class, android-audiomanager

I have a widget and i am trying to set my phone volume silent mode without using `Activity`

My `widget` class :

```
   public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {



  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
      int[] appWidgetIds) {


    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
        MyWidget.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {



      RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
          R.layout.widget_layout);

      Intent i = new Intent(context,mutee.class);
      PendingIntent i1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, 0);
      remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton4silent, i1);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
  }
}
```

Now i want to use mutee `class` and set my phone volume `silent`
I actually tried this but it doesnt work :

```
public class mutee  {

    private Context context;    


     mutee(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }

    private void setRingerMode (int ringerMode){

        AudioManager e = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        //ringerMode=0x00000002;//normal
        e.setRingerMode(ringerMode);


    }

     mutee() {
         setRingerMode(0x00000002);
    }

}
```

Comment: you sure you have permission android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS like this to do so ?

Comment: yes  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" ></uses-permission>

Comment: what mode you are passing ?

Comment: normal i think... i copied that value from here [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#RINGER_MODE_NORMAL)

Comment: AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT use this instead

Answer (score 1):

You can hold your application context in a reference which you can pass on to your helper class easily.
In your context you need to pass that reference to your Mute.class

Code Snippet to Hold your application reference throught out the Application:-

```
public class YourApplication extends Application{
  static YourApplication yourapplication;

  public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            yourapplication = this;
   }
   public static YourApplication getApplication()
    {
            return yourapplication;
    }
  public void onTerminate() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onTerminate();
    }
}
```

Now as `yourapplication` hold the context of your application,

You can call `getSystemService()`on it.

Code Snippet:-

```
 AudioManager am;
 am= (AudioManager)yourapplication.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
 am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

You need to call YourApplication extends Application from your Manifest file

```
<application 
android:label="@string/app_name"
...
android:name="com.abc.demo.YourApplication"
...>
```

Comment: Code Snippet should be added onCreate() method?

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you tell me the excact code that i should use? because from what i did i could not set my phone silent....

Comment: @noobProgrammer : Can you tell me what error or exception come across your way?. You can create class which extends Application and add that  class in <application> tag of your manifest file. Use that application  context throughout your application.